# how to create picker menu like drop down in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am using a picker. Onclick textField, it shows the picker menu. But picker options show the top of the textField. Onclick textField toggle shows
Here is the image

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    struct PickerView: View {
    
    @State private var text:String = ""
    @State private var options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
    @State private var selectedOption = "Option 1"
    @State private var showPicker: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
                HStack {
                    TextField("", text: $selectedOption)
                        .disabled(true)
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.gray)
                .cornerRadius(5.0)

                Picker("Options", selection: $selectedOption) {
                    ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                       Text(option).tag(option)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.automatic)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(5.0)
                .shadow(radius: 5)
                .offset(y: -100)
                .opacity(showPicker ? 1 : 0)
                .animation(.default)
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                self.showPicker.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

How to show the picker onClick textField directly like drop down?

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you wanted

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack {
            Picker("Options", selection: $selectedOption) {
                ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                    Text(option).tag(option)
                }
            }
            .tint(.black)
            .pickerStyle(.menu)

            Spacer()
        }
        .background(.gray)
        .cornerRadius(5.0)
    }
}
```